# Redux Form: Field not passing validation despite already being pre-populated with values

Tags: validation, react-native, redux-form

I have a form called `UpdateForm` with some fields:

- Title
- URL
- Tags

The form fields are already pre-populated with values, which the user can alter as they wish and update.

[image]

One caveat though is that when you open the `UpdateForm` screen and press 'Update' without altering any fields, the field that is initially touched on opening the screen does not pass validation despite having values that should allow it to pass validation.

In the example above, the 'Tags' field is initially touched when I open the screen and then when I press 'Update', the Tags field receives a validation error.

The only way to get it to pass validation is to click out of that input field.

`UpdateForm.js`:

```
return (
      <View style={formContainer}>
        <View style={headerContainer}>
          <Text style={headerText}>Update Bookmark</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={inputContainer}>
          <Field name="title" label="Title" component={Input} val={title} />
          <Field name="url" label="URL" component={Input} val={url} />
          <Field name="tags" label="Tags" component={Input} val={tagsString} />
          <View style={buttonContainer}>
            <Button color="#007aff" onPress={ this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>Update</Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  const URL_REGEX = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/;

  if (!values.title) {
    errors.title = "Please provide a title";
  }

  if (!values.url || !URL_REGEX.test(values.url)) {
    errors.url = "Please provide a valid URL";
  }

  if (!values.tags) {
    errors.tags = "Please provide some tags separated by commas";
  }

  return errors;
}

UpdateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'updateForm',
  validate
})(UpdateForm);
```

`Input` field component:

```
const Input = ({ input: { onChange, ...restInput }, label, val, meta: { error, touched } }) => {
  const {
    inputBox,
    labelText,
    inputContainer,
    errorContainer,
    errorText
  } = styles;
  console.log('Touched:', touched, val);
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={inputContainer}>
        <Text style={labelText}>{label}</Text>
        <TextInput
          { ...restInput }
          style={inputBox}
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          clearButtonMode='while-editing'
          autoFocus={true}
          value={val}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={errorContainer}>
        <Text style={errorText}>{touched && error}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

  );
};
```

**tldr;** First touched input field not passing validation despite being touched and having prepopulated values to pass validation. Need to click out of the input field before it passes validation. How to fix?

**EDIT:**

The way I am currently passing initial values to my field inputs is quite complicated.

Top level I have a `BookmarkList` component which fetches all bookmarks from remote API server. Each bookmark carries its own title, URL and tags values.

`title`, `URL` and `tags` values are passed from `BookmarkList` to `BookmarkDetail`, which renders each individual bookmark:

```
class BookmarkList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'My Bookmarks'
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchBookmarkList();
  }

  renderBookmarks() {
    return this.props.bookmarks.map(bookmark =>
      <BookmarkDetail key={bookmark.title} bookmark={bookmark} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderBookmarks()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Each `BookmarkDetail` carries an 'Update' button, which pushes parameters via navigator like so:

```
<Button color='#007aff' onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('UpdateBookmark', {
              _id: _id,
              title: title,
              url: url,
              tags: tags
            })}>
              Update
            </Button>
```

Then in `UpdateForm`, I grab those initial values using `navigation.getParam` like so before setting them in the input fields:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
    const _id = navigation.getParam('_id', 'NO-ID');
    const title = navigation.getParam('title', 'NO-TITLE');
    const url = navigation.getParam('url', 'NO-URL');
    const tags = navigation.getParam('tags', 'NO-TAGS');
    const tagsString = tags.join(", ");
```

Comment: how did you pass initial states to form fields?

Comment: I pass them down a component as a prop, before pushing them via `this.props.navigation.navigate`. Check my latest edit

Comment: wrong way to use `redux form`  `Field`