# Redux Field validation fails after supplying a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, datepicker

**A little context:**

I have a form in which the user needs to select a date from a date picker, then submit the form with the selected date and some other pre-populated information. I am using Redux Field to wrap a custom component which includes the React Date Picker.

**The problem**:

I am using the validate prop for Redux `<Field>`, which simply enforces that the input value not be undefined. The problem is when I select a date I see the error message that I would normally see when validation fails. In other words the app thinks the date picker input value is undefined even though it clearly has a value.
[image]

**Troubleshooting**

I console logged this.props and checked the React Components Tab in dev tools, and observed the prop in question, "moveInDate", before and after selecting a date. I see an empty string prior to selecting a date (this is expected since I am setting an empty string as an initial value), and I see the expected value after selecting a date.
[image]

I also console logged the input value in the wrapped component, and I can see the name of the element and selected value are making down into it.

At this point I'm not sure where to look. Everything is updating as it should from what I can tell, yet the app still sees the input as having a value of undefined some how. I feel I am missing something as it relates to handling the input with Redux. It is useful to note I'm using this Field implementation on another page in the app, and it works without issue. I speculate there must be something elsewhere in the parent component messing with the state, but I'm not sure what to look for.

On a related note, I have a similar issue when selecting a dropdown that is also wrapped in Redux `<Field>`: the dropdown options don't always display, and I get the same validation bug as described above when I am able to select an option. I don't mean to get off topic with this, but I can't help but feel these issues are related.

I will post code I think will be helpful, but it is quite a lot in its entirety.

**Field:**

```
<Field
  highlightDates={busyDates}
  name="moveInDate"
  type="text"
  component={DateField}
  label="Installation Date"
  onChange={moveInDate =>
    this.handleMoveInDateChange(
      moveInDate,
      leaseLength
    )
  }
  validate={[required, this.dateAvailable]}
  filterDate={(date) => {
    const day = date.day();
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }}
  minDate={
    mode === MODE_RENEW &&
    formValues?.currentMoveOutDate !== null
      ? moment(formValues?.currentMoveOutDate)
      : moment().add(settings.blackoutPeriod, 'days')
  }
  maxDate={
    mode === MODE_RENEW &&
    formValues?.currentMoveOutDate !== null &&
    moment(formValues?.currentMoveOutDate).add(1, 'week')
  }
  openToDate={
    formValues?.moveInDate ||
    this.getFirstAvailableDateForMoveIn()
  }
```

**Validate Rule**

```
export const required = value => value ? undefined : 'You can\'t leave this empty';
```

**Handler:**

```
  handleMoveInDateChange(moveInDate, leaseLength) {
    const newMoveOutDate = getMoveOutDateByMoveInDate(
      moveInDate,
      leaseLength,
      this.getBusyMoveOutDates()
    );

    if (leaseLength && moveInDate) {
      this.props.formValues.moveOutDate = newMoveOutDate;
    }
  }
```

The handler simply calculates a move out date based on the move in date, then adds it to form values. There isn't a move out date picker in the form. I thought this handler could be causing a problem, but it's not doing anything with the move in date (the problematic input).

**Final thought:**
My question is admittedly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236909/redux-form-field-not-passing-validation-despite-already-being-pre-populated-wit), but in my case the issue arises when inputting a new value, and not from dealing with a preloaded value.

**Update**
I noticed when selecting a date in the datepicker, the value never changes. I refactored the validate rule with braces so I could console log the arg, and there is nothing making it into the function. Conversely when I try this on another page using the same `<Field>` with datepicker I see the new value each time I change it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` in the redux connect code.

I discovered the date picker was working correctly when I commented out the values I was assigning in initialValues in mapStateToProps, so it looks like the problem was the date picker always thought it had a pristine value, which is why the redux field never thought the value changed (from null to the selected value), so the validation logic didn't think anything was in there!

Hope this helps someone who stumbled across a similar problem.